# How to use scoped_model with Navigator?

Tags: dart, flutter, navigation, state, scoped-model

I am use `scoped_model` for manage app state.

I have `AuthModel` for auth state. When user log in I change `screen` in `AuthModel`:

```
  Widget screen = LoadScreen();

  if (loggedIn == true) {
    screen = HomeScreen;
  } else if (loggedIn == false) {
    screen = LoginScreen;
  }
```

But I get error when I call in `RootPage` Widget:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(‘/${model.screen}’);
```

> ‘Package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart’: Failed assertion: line
>   2106 pos 12: ‘!_debugLocked’: is not true’

`RootPage` is first page in Flutter app and is use for show load screen until auth return if user is sign in or not:

```
class RootPage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ScopedModelDescendant<AuthModel>(builder: (context, child, model) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(‘/${model.screen}’); 
    });
  }
}
```

Why I am get this error?

How can use `scoped_model` for do navigation if user is sign in or out?

Thanks!